# Round Metal Gate Fence Post is Spinning When Gate is Opened

Tags: repair, fence, gate-post

I need to correct a small problem with a metal gate post.  When the gate is opened to its full opening, the leverage of the gate pulling against the gate post causes the post to spin inside the post hole and then the gate becomes misaligned with the attachment mechanism (on the right of the gate).  Other than this, the post itself is very secure and stable.  In the attached image, the post on the left of the gate spins inside of its post hole when the gate is opened fully.  Additional image is provided to give you more detail on the post installation.

I'm trying to find a remedy to stop the post from spinning, but that does not require removing the fence post. Why? -- I don't believe there is adequate space around the post to dig it out and reseat it (due to the large amount of concrete surrounding the post).

Please let me know what ideas you have.

Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like the hinges are part of the problem.  They stop "hinging"  prematurely and then the post spins.  Have you considered getting a different type of hinge??

Comment: Are you reaching limits of travel on the hinge?

Comment: That is correct.  As the gate opens to its furthest point, the hinges stop the motion from going any further, and that is when the post starts to spin.

Comment: One additional question:  an idea I had was to use some metal shims that I pound in around the post to tighten the seating of the post.  I assume that is a risky approach because I could possibly crack the cement that is holding it.  I'd appreciate your thoughts on that option also.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there anywhere on the ground around the gate that you could mount a door stop that would prevent the gate from swinging that far open? The only reason I hesitated to make this an answer is that all that concrete around the gate implies a sidewalk where a floor-mounted doorstop would be a trip-hazard.

Comment: That is a GREAT idea.  I love crowdsourcing input.  Thank you @MosheKatz.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the post has a couple straps around it, one of which connects to the top bar of the fence.  Try putting a bolt or self-tapping screw through this strap into the post.  This way the post will be kept from spinning by being locked into the fence more securely.

Comment: I'd be concerned that someone forcing the gate open could apply a whole lot of torque, likely shearing any such bolt. Maybe a big one...

Comment: Perhaps - at some point to post tube will likely shear before the bolt. Mentally I was thinking maybe 1/4” to 3/8”?

Comment: 1/8" tek screws should be plenty, the connection to top of the fence does not look very strong.

Answer (score 0):

Get a wider gate and fit the hinges behind the post so that the gate can swing flat against the fence without hitting the post.

The hinges are trying to go there already, they can't be stopped with that big lever available.  If you try to stop them it's only a question of what will break.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a place you can put it that won't be a trip hazard, a doorstop attached to the ground will prevent the gate from swinging too far.

The simplest (but not the nicest-looking) way to do it is just a piece of corner brace, like this one: [Everbilt    4 in. Zinc-Plated Corner Brace (2-Pack)](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-4-in-Zinc-Plated-Corner-Brace-2-Pack-15309/202033899)

There are lots of other options, including fancier metal pieces, wooden blocks, fake (or real) rocks screwed to the ground, etc.